# How do I create a minimal install for Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista

I have already installed Windows Vista. I am running XBMC on it and would like to try to remove and turn off as many unnecessary features of Windows as possible to create an appliance-like effect.

I need the box to be able to:

- access the internet (via Wi-Fi)
- enable networking for file sharing

but most of the other Windows features are unnecessary.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

How about [vLite](http://www.vlite.net/about.html)?  I haven't tried it but I think you could achieve what you want with its component removal feature.

Comment: Hmm seems like nLite for XP and another one from them for Vista, it seems you can play with Vista without hesitation like you can play using nLite with XP. :)

Comment: Yes, I saw vLite (via Google) but I didn't know if there was  a better way to get an appliance on-off effect  with Vista. I know that my expectations can't be too high because Windows is a pretty heavy OS (it does a lot of things) but I was wondering if anyone else had a better suggestion than using vLite.

Comment: In that case, off topic from the OP, but have you explored the possibility of using a different OS with XBMC on top?  XBMC's Ubuntu ISOs don't exactly boot instantly on my old hardware but maybe on newer stuff they're close to what you want (I can't imagine XBMC launching at "appliance speed" within and after the booting of Windows, either...), or maybe someone has made a sort of XBMC "lite" distro...